# Update 1 row at a time and each row has a different value when using x-editable for the same user

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo, x-editable

I have a HTML table with, for this example, 2 rows (could be more). The middle column is editable and each row in the HTML table is a different column in the database. When I edit row 1 and refresh the page row 2 now has the same value as row 1. I do not want this. The user id (pk) will be the same for each row. The documentation about [creating a new record](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html#newrecord) says this would work with updating existing, but does not really help me. I am looking for as much help as I can get.

Here is an image of my table:
[image]

How do I get each row to keep its value and not update all other rows?

For example if I update the column in row 1, I want only row 1's column to be updated.

Please help!

Here is my code:

HTML Code:

```
<td><a class="myeditable" data-name="fb_url"  data-type="text" data-pk="<?php echo ($userid);?>" title="Edit"><?php echo ($result['fb_url']);?></a></td>                    
<td><a class="myeditable" data-name="tw_url" data-type="text" data-pk="<?php echo ($userid);?>" title="Edit"><?php echo ($result['tw_url']);?></a></td>
```

Post.php Code

```
require("config.php");

$pk = $_POST['pk'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$value = $_POST['value'];

    if(!empty($value)) {
            try // save user selection to the database
              {
                $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE social_preferences SET fb_url = :fburl, tw_url = :twurl WHERE user_id = :userID AND ");
                $stmt->bindParam(":userID", $pk, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $stmt->bindParam(':twurl', $value);
                $stmt->bindParam(':fburl', $value);
                $stmt->execute();
               }  catch(PDOException $e) { echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage(); }
    }else {
        echo 'No value...';
    }
```

JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//toggle `popup` / `inline` mode
$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';       


    $('.myeditable').editable({
            url: 'post.php',
            ajaxOptions: {
                type: 'post',
            },
            success: function(data, config) {
                if(data && data.id) {
                     //set pk
                    $(this).editable('option', 'pk', data.id);                 
                }
            }
    });
});
```

When I check the network tab in Chrome dev tools I see this:
Method: POST
Status: 302 Moved Temporarily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP is talking about rows, but in fact it are columns.

```
$accepted_names = array('fb_url', 'tw_url');
if (in_array($_POST['name'], $accepted_names)) {
    if(!empty($_POST['value'])) {
        $value = $_POST['value'];
        $id = $_POST['pk'];
        try {
            $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE social_preferences SET ' . $_POST['name'] . ' = :value
                                  WHERE user_id = :id');
            $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(':value',$value);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
        catch (PDOExeption $e) {
            echo json_encode(array('status' => 'failed', 'msg' => $e->getMessage()));
            exit;
        }
        echo json_encode(array('id' => $id, 'status' => 'oké', 'msg' => $value));
    }
    else {
         echo jsonencode(array('status' => 'failed', 'msg' => 'No value ....'));
    }
}
else {
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 422 Unprocessable entity');
}
```

Comment: You are right about the columns my apologies about not being clear in my question. I added your code and when I try to update the column in the first row it just resets back to the original value. When I try to update the column in the 2nd row I receive this error:`Unprocessable entity`. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I fixed the issue with `Unprocessable entity`, but it does not update the value. It will reset to the original value after I submit the new value.

Comment: Added id field to JSON response in case of success

Comment: I updated my code and it is still not updating. I can see the new value but when the page refreshes the new value gets reset back to the original value

Comment: That means that nothing is being updated, check the source code from your page if the right id's (data-pk) are assigned and/or include the POST vars in the json response

Comment: When I use Chrome Dev Tool and look at the network tab after I submit my new value I see the for data. Take a look at this [image](http://i27.photobucket.com/albums/c171/mystreetlife_/form-data_zps937583f5.png) the new value is there, but it will get reset. It never actually updates the database.

Comment: It's not important what's in the Chrome Dev Tools, but which values are posted to PHP. If something is not working as aspected you need to figure out why. That's called **debugging**. How to do that is up to you, I just gave some hints

Comment: Thanks. I'm still pretty new to coding so I have never had to debug on this level yet (not sure where to being), but thanks for your help. Once I can figure out the answer to my question I will mark this as solved.

Comment: I think the easiest way to begin is to create a page with form which simulates the ajax request, and see if it's working correctly. If it is, the problem is in JS, else it's somewhere else. Or just run the UPDATE query in your favorite (My)SQL tool

Comment: Not to sure how to simulate ajax request or what MySQL too to use, but I will do some research. Thanks.

Comment: I used Firefox debugger and received this error: `Call to undefined method PDOStatement::bindParameter()` so I changed `bindParameter` to `bindParam` and everything is working ok now. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you use oracle SQL.

Put all the users you want to update in an array and use foreach to iterate over them.

Execute your update statement for every one.

I don't know if it is possible to run multiple updates in one statement, but I don't think so.

EDIT:To be sure that only one row is affected use unique identifiers such as user ids if possible.

Comment: it will only be 1 user and that user will be able to update multiple rows.

Comment: Sure, but this is not what i meant. I don't know if there is a way to concatenate multiple update statements to execute them with one execute.

Comment: This does not help me.

Comment: Well if my answer doesn't help you add more details to your question please, because until now you want to know how to update multiple rows and for this i wrote an answer.

Comment: I added more details in my question. Please take a look. Keep in mind I am using X-editable to do my inline editing.

Answer (score 0):

in fact , you just need to follow the documentation of the X - table in here 
[X-Table](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/index.html)

Ok, this is a information tag.
data-name="your field column in database" 
data-pk="your primary key" in data pk you can input multiple PK.

Now please try this example.

HTML:

```
<td>
   <a class="myeditable" data-name="fb_url"  data-type="text" data-pk="<?php echo $userid;?>" data-url="post.php" title="Edit"><?php echo ($result['fb_url']);?></a>
</td>
```

JS Code:

```
<script>  
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.myeditable').editable();
        });
    </script>
```

Post.php Code

```
if(!empty($_POST['name'])) {
 $pk = $_POST['pk']; // post from data-pk
     $name = $_POST['name']; // post from data-name
     $value = $_POST['value']; // this is your value
            $stmt=$db->prepare("UPDATE social_preferences SET $name= '".$value."' WHERE your_id= '".$pk."'");
            $stmt->execute();
}else {
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 422 Unprocessable entity');
}
```